# Search special chars by space in sphinx

Tags: sphinx

i have problem with sphinx search.
I have string for indexing

**xyz a'qwerty**

I need to find it if i use

**xy** - ok

**xy a** - ok

**xyz a'qwerty** - ok

**xyz a qwerty** - ok

**xyz a qwe** - not ok

I rly can't reach right result, know someone how to do this?
My index look like this, regex_filters was some experiments so, can be removed.

```
index ProductSearch
{
    source          = ProductSearchSource
    path            = c:/wamp/sphinx/data/product
    docinfo         = extern
    enable_star     = 0
    expand_keywords = 1
    min_word_len    = 2
    min_prefix_len  = 1
    charset_type    = utf-8
    charset_table   = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+0022, U+0026, U+0027, U+0060, U+00B4, U+002E, U+0e1->a, U+0c1->a, U+10d->c, U+10c->c, U+10f->d, U+10e->d, U+0e9->e, U+0c9->e, U+11b->e, U+11a->e, U+0ed->i, U+0cd->i, U+148->n, U+147->n, U+0f3->o, U+0d3->o, U+159->r, U+158->r, U+161->s, U+160->s, U+165->t, U+164->t, U+0fa->u, U+0da->u, U+16f->u, U+16e->u, U+0fd->y, U+0dd->y, U+17e->z, U+17d->z,
    wordforms       = c:/wamp/www/project/configs/sphinx/synonyms
    regexp_filter   = (\w*)'(\w*) => \1'\2
    regexp_filter   = (\w*)'(\w*) => \1 \2
    regexp_filter   = (\w*)'(\w*) => \1
    regexp_filter   = (\w*)'(\w*) => \2


}
```

Using SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2

PS.: Sorry for bad english

Comment: Added source of index. I need found it if i use every posible substring of word and find it too if i write space instead of apostrophe. but it dont work if i use last example

Comment: OK, remove the  `PHP` Tag, it seems that is a `sphinx` related question.  And also i dont now sphinx.

Comment: Done. Srry it's my first question here

Comment: No problem, i just want to help you to get it answered by someone who  know that stuff.

Comment: I think you need to stop and think about the 'rules' you trying to enforce. At the moment, not clear why your last example is 'not ok'. Why shouldnt that match? You seem to want 'part word' matching as xy would match. For example is it because querty is a long word? as its not the first word?

Comment: If you want help, you need to explain a little better what you want and what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I missed synonyms in wordforms, it rewrites my tested word, so it looked like sphinx doesn't work correctly.. (Facepalm here)